# Apache httpd connection refused during stress test using jmeter

Tags: apache, jmeter, connection-refused

Now, I do stress test using jemter in windows(jmeter.bat).

```
Number of Threads = 100
Ramp-up period = 0 
Loop count = 1000
```

But raise connection refused error in jmeter, after 20~30 seconds. 
I can not find connection refused error in /usr/local/apache/logs/error.log or /usr/local/apache/logs/access.log.

Test is HTTP GET, index.html("It's works")
Apache MPM is worker and setting below:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers            8
MinSpareThreads         64
MaxSpareThreads        1024 
ThreadsPerChild         64
MaxRequestWorkers       512
MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

jmeter problem? any apache setting problem?

jmeter exception below:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://checkout.teledit.com refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a jmeter issue:

- check components between jmeter and apache (firewall, load balancer, ddos protection ...)
- check apache settings, to check this rampup slowly and see starting from which load you get those errors.